# Default.a.map is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

as a beginner I'am having trouble getting the data from my product data file
I follow a online tutorial but I'm stuck with this issue :

```
react-dom.development.js:20135 Uncaught TypeError: _productsData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.map is not a function
at Products (Products.js:9)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:15425)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15956)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19228)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20165)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20075)
at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20049)
at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:19904)
at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19711)
at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:20415)
at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:20441)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:20509)
at ReactRoot.push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:20820)
at react-dom.development.js:20974
at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:20292)
at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:20970)
at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:21037)
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.0 (serviceWorker.js:135)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1import React from "react";
```

I've been searching around without clear answers.

here is my index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Products from './Products';

ReactDOM.render(<Products />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and my Products.js file with the function to get the props from individual Product.js

```js
import React from "react"

import Product from "./Product"
import productsData from "./productsData"


function Products(){
 
  const productComponents = productsData.map(item => 
   <Product product={item}/>)

    return (
    <div>
      <h1>{productComponents}</h1>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Products
```

as well as my Product.js with the props

```js
import React from "react"

function Product(props) {
   
     return (
            <div>
               <h2>{props.product.name}</h2>
            </div>
        )
}

export default Product
```

and of course my data file

```js
   const product =
   [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "house",
    price : "250666"
  }, 
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "cake",
    price : "4000"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "car",
    price: "54000"
  }  
]
```

The thing that bugs me is it works fine in the demo but not when I'm doing EXACTLY the same thing !!

Please help 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44&t=6038s) -around  1h50 or so

Comment: you need to export default of your product data file to make this work like you want

Comment: write `export default product` in last line of your data file

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It was really simple and now it's working. I guess I haven't seen that in the tutorial. Now I can resume my course.Thanks again and wish you the Best

Answer (score 7):

In your data file, you need to **export** it as well.
Just add `export default product;` at the end of the data file.

Answer (score 0):

the .map() isn't a function error occures because you are not iterating a list
Try using forEach() instead
Sincerely hope it works for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).